# initMap(); or any custom function on redraw of Datatables

Tags: jquery, google-maps, datatables, maps, datatables-1.10

***Please have somebody idea how initialize other function which doesn't have something with tables on redraw of dataTable ?***

Here is the way how you can get array data from dataTables on every change like sort, search, pageview if you're serverside. if no serverside it's works also but you need custom action for search only.. sort, view will works

in my case i want use the array from dataTables by showing my mapMarkers on everychange with DataTables. By drawCallback is everytihng putting into form_data global variable

```
var x_table = $('#myTable')
     
.DataTable({
    paging: true,
    info: true,
    searching: true,
    searchable: true,
    pageLength: 25,
    // scrollY: 350,
    fixedHeader: true,
    order: [[0, 'desc']],
    // aaSorting: [[0, 'desc']],
    columnDefs: [
        { name : 'id', targets: 0, type: 'string',},
        { name : 'title', targets: 1,},
        // { name : 'status', targets: 0, },
        { name : 'description', targets: 2, },
        { name : 'address', targets: 5, },
        { name : 'lat', targets: 4, },
        { name : 'lng', targets: 3, },
        // { name : 'gps_status', targets: 0,},
        { name : 'distance_to', targets: 6,},
    ],
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '{{ path('test_service') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
    },
    drawCallback: function() {
 
        window.form_data = this.api().rows().data();
 
        console.log(form_data);
        console.log(form_data[0][0]);
        console.log( 'Records on draw event lenght ->  ' +form_data.length);
        console.log( 'Redraw occurred at: '+new Date().getTime() );
    }
    // rowId: 'id'
})
 
// .on( 'draw', function () {
//     initMap();
// })
 
;
```

Now i need to reinit function for google maps initMap(); on every drawCallback but if i will uncomment line .on() the drawCallback stop works but initMap(); will initalized...

i tried something like this

```
$('#myTable').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
 
    initMap();
    alert( 'Table redrawn' );
});
```

but the table stop working... initMap(); will initialized.. but table will stop working...
Here i provide video

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qLtXGSUIsp62PE6QLnLTZhC0SKqbCxy1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qLtXGSUIsp62PE6QLnLTZhC0SKqbCxy1/view?usp=sharing)

Issue is here (in video) that it stops after first sort load the ajax request... but if i tried same with dataTable without serverside data... the issue was the same that after first sort or pageview was .on() function initialized and dataTable stopped worked...

now only solution which i have is button under map:

```
$( "#updateMap" ).click(function() {
   initMap();
});
```

and button

```
<button id='updateMap'>Load form_data variable</button>
```

which on click load new values in variable form_data and update markers on map.

I  want do this automatically... not by click event.. but still looking solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Great news !!!

If you want add other function like initMap(); where i loaded the google maps + markers and reinitialize it on every new redrawn of dataTables, because i load new data by ajax that i need load new markers positions with info windows for each marker

i change my code which i had commented in main example

```
.on( 'draw', function () {
    initMap();
})
```

and used this and i am now able to load custom function like initMap(); on every redraw of query by ajax post request

```
.on( 'draw.dt', initMap )
```

Now if i load on every ajax request new dataset... because eg. i searching or sorting the data... will also show new markers on my map by reinitialize of google map function.

Hope that it helps somebody :)